# Django: How can I filter based on a value in a one-to-many child

Tags: django

I'm developing an auction site.  I have a model that represents items being auctioned and a model representing bids.  An item may have zero, one or more bids.  The bid model includes a User object representing the bidder.  The bidder may bid for more than one item.  Using the ListView class based view, I'd like to list all items that a particular user is bidding for.

The following sample code represents the problem:

```
# models.py

class Item(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.description}'


# A car can have zero, one or many paints
class AuctionBid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING,
    )
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.item} - {self.buyer} - {self.bid}'
```

```
# views.py

from .models import Item, AuctionBid
class AuctionListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'listing/item_list.html'  # change from default template name

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.order_by('description').filter(?????)
```

What do I need to put in the AuctionListView get_queryset() so that I can return only items where a certain user has made a bid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add `related_name` to item field in `AuctionBid` model so accessing it would be easier:

```
class AuctionBid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item,
        on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name="bids"
    )
```

Then you can use this filter:

```
Item.objects.order_by('description').filter(bids__buyer=self.request.user).distinct()
```

***Note that not using `distinct` method might cause your queryset to contain duplicate rows.***

Comment: That's brilliant.  Works perfectly.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using the model `AuctionBid` in your filter you can retrieve all items for that particular user.

```py
Item.objects.filter(auctionbid__buyer=self.request.user).order_by('description')
```

Comment: @Navid Zarepak is correct - you need the .distinct() call because without it you do indeed get multiple rows.